# Where to write custom SCSS in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am developing ASP.NET website with bootstrap. I want to use cards column as layout. I read the tutorial in [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns). At the button, there is a code like this:

```
.card-columns {
  @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
    column-count: 4;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(xl) {
    column-count: 5;
  }
}
```

I khow the code is to set number of columns  to 4 if the screen is large (lg) and to 5 if the screen is extra large (xl).

My question is where to write this code? I try write in html head part but not work. My page use bootstrap from CDN (not from local folder).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: SCSS files are like other CSS files. So you have to put them just after the bootstrapcdn like.

Comment: No, SASS needs to be compiled to CSS first on the server. Browsers don't understand SASS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need install SCSS compiler in visual studio, after compile the scss file you get a .css code.

Greetings.